# Convert list to string in python such that it separates the each integer as an element

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list

```
f=['20.0', '21.0', '22.0', '23.0', '24.0', '25.0', '26.0', '27.0',
   '28.0', '29.0', '30.0', '31.0', '32.0', '33.0']
```

I want to change the list to string such that each element is recognized as an integer 20 21... That is `f[0]=20`, `f[1]=21`.
If I just use `f=str(f)`, then it will count `['` as an element too.

Comment: `new_list = list(map(float, f))`

Comment: If `f[0] == 20` then you're not converting the list to a string. You're converting it to a list of numbers.

Comment: @Barmar Yes it is an integer, but on the next step on the program I have  it accepts the option f as an string only. That is why I need to covert the list integer element to string.

Comment: So you just need to remove `.0` from each of the strings?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

`f = list(map(lambda x : int(float(x)), f))`

if you want the list to still contain elements of type string instead of int just do it like this:

`f = list(map(lambda x : str(int(float(x))), f))`

Answer (score 0):

```
f = [float(element) for element in f]
```

Comment: Or if you want int, `f = [int(float(element)) for element in f]`